# ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'class1'

Tags: python

I have this error:

[image]

My project structure is:

[image]

All `__init__.py` are empty

**main.py**

```
from testclass import class1
from testclass import class2
l1 = class1()
l2 = class2()
```

**class1.py**

```
class class1():
    def __init__(self):
        print('hello')
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        ldummy = class1()`
```

**class2.py**

```
import class1
class class2(class1.class1):
    def __init__(self):
    class1.class1.__init__(self)
    print('hola')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ldummy = class2()
```

I don't see what's not good about that

Comment: After `from testclass import class1` you technically need to scope as `l1 = class1.class1()` where the first part is the module and the second part is the actual class name

Comment: from class1 import class1, it should be like this

Comment: @CoryKramer issue is raising during this line `from testclass import class2`

Comment: @LakshikaParihar ==> same error

Comment: From which directory you are running your file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read your error message carefully, you will see that the actual error occurs when `class2` tries to import `class1` which it cannot. The reason for that is that the reference remains the level where main is located even for `class2`. So you need this content in `class2`:

```py
from testclass import class1 # Instead of import class1
class class2(class1.class1):
    def __init__(self):
    class1.class1.__init__(self)
    print('hola')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ldummy = class2()
```

EDIT:

Answering your comment:
There are a few ways to achieve the desired behaviour, but I wouldn't necessarily say that they are pythonic. Before importing, you can add the main folder to the python path in class2.py

```
import sys
def import():
    sys.path.append(main_path)
```

Alternatively you could also add the path permanently to the python path.
A third option is to use a try-except-clause around your import:

```
try:
    from testclass import class1
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    import class1
```

I would argue that none of these options are great and could eventually cause errors. Better to have clear and unique ways of calling your functions.

Comment: @C Hecht ==> Ok that is working from main.py. Thanks a lot for that. But now, it is not working when I execute class2.py. what needs to be done to make both work?

Comment: See my edit to the answer regarding your second question

Comment: You rock C Hecht !

Comment: Happy to help. If you consider this question answered, then please mark the answer as correct.