# How do I import a function from a file in a directory on the same 'level' as my current directory

Tags: python

Say my file tree is as shown below. What I want to do, is while in the directory `code`, import all functions/classes from `helpers.py` and `agents.py` into `main.py`, and run whatever I need to run. This used to work before I added a dependency on a function in `helpers.py` to `agents.py`. Lets call this function `some_function`.

**question:** What import statement do I need to include to make sure that I can use `some_function` in `agents.py`, while running `main.py` from `code`?

**What I have tried:** I figured it would make sense to include the `__init__.py` in the `code` directory, and then use the following import statement: `from code.helpers import some_function` at the top of `agents.py`. However, this gives me the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'code.helpers'; 'code' is not a package`.

```
code
├── __init__.py
├── agents
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── agents.py
├── helpers
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── helpers.py
├── main.py
└── test.py
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68578390/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-class1/68578546#68578546 and see whether that answers your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `agents.py` script and type `from helpers.helpers import some_functions`

to import funtions or clases from one py file to another you use keyword `from` and you specify location, then you use keyword `import` to import.

```
from <folder><script_name> import <class_name or function_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **init**.py marks directory as a package. Package and modules names are what is used in the import statements. The structure you provide means that you have following structure:

- package `code` with
- sub-package `agents` with

  - module `agents`, containing your code
- sub-package `helpers` with

  - module `helpers`, containing your code

To import function into main, it is recommended that you use absolute imports, i.e.
`from code.agents.agents import your_fun`

It seems you are missing the name of your module in your import.